# Stackoverflow data dump sites?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Has anyone seen any non abusive sites pop up yet that makes use of the stackoverflow data dump?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created [SPWho2.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20091216035532/http://spwho2.com/), a statistics analysis dump for Stack Overflow.  I built it so that I can throw in the database dumps for Server Fault and Super User when those become available too.

I'm super-anal about not being abusive with it.  If there's anything that anybody wants to see added to make it more clear about where the real data lives, let me know and I'll be happy to implement it.  I'm never going to show the question content or answer content on SPWho2 because I don't want to distract the search engines.  Every author page and question name links back to Stack Overflow.

I also created [wiki articles about importing & analyzing the StackOverflow export](https://web.archive.org/web/20100206074754/http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Data_Mining_the_StackOverflow_Database) over at SQLServerPedia.

Comment: cool, great site.

Comment: @Brent We just got a flag about SPWho2.com being down. Is that permanent?

Comment: Ah, that's been offline for years, actually.